# PHP Mysql Update Product Stock/Qty

Tags: php, product

[image]

Hello. I'm having a hard time with this. What i'm to do is discount the stock of certain product every time that a new entry is created (MYSql INSERT). So, the idea is INSERT the entry then UPDATE the Stock/Qty of the product that was sold.

Table Entrys for INSERT
Table products UPDATE (idprod, stock, description)

This is my Qty input

```
<input type="text" name="txtQty<?=$i;?>" id="txtQty<?=$i;?>" value="1" size="3">
```

This is my MYSql Sentence after the INSERT

```
$sql_Qty = "UPDATE products SET stock = stock - '".$_POST['txtQty$i']."' WHERE idprod = '".$_POST['txtidp$i']."'";
$objQueryQty = mysql_query($sql_Qty);
```

Thanks!

Comment: offtopic: do not just dump your $_POST contents into the database. Look at "MySQL Injections". This is huge security risk.

Comment: What exactly is your qustion? If something isn't working the way you expect please explain what is actually happening, and what should be happening.

Comment: Look into using prepared statements with PDO or MySQLi, mysql_ functions have been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks guys for your advice. But this is a short and basic version of the original code. Like you see is in Spanish. Mike-W theidea is UPDATE the Qty after INSERT a new entry. The problem is that the update doen't work. @broken-heart Sorry. No luck friend. What could be wrong? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UPDATE query should be this:

```
$sql_Qty = "UPDATE products SET `stock` = 'stock-".$_POST['txtQty'.$i]."' WHERE `idprod` = '".$_POST['txtidp'.$i]."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Just a very little fix in the Broken Heart Sentence.

```
$sql_Qty = "UPDATE products SET `stock` = stock-'".$_POST['txtQty'.$i]."' WHERE `idprod` = '".$_POST['txtidp'.$i]."'";
```